# RPM + error during build RPM

Tags: linux

please advice why I get the error "Bad file: /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/test.sh"

I need to create rpm file ,

I only have the spec file under SPECS

and the test.sh script under SOURCES

what’s wrong here?

```
 [root@linux /usr/src/redhat]# ls

 BUILD  RPMS  SOURCES  SPECS  SRPMS
```

the spec file:

```
Summary: An example tool. To show a simple rpm build of the tool.
Name: test.sh
Version: 6.2
Release: 2
Source:/root/test.sh
Group: Development/Debuggers
BuildRoot:/var/tmp/test.sh
%description


Bad file: /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/test.sh: No such file or directory RPM build     errors:    Bad file: /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/test.sh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to sources is *never* used; *all* source files *must* be in `%{_sourcedir}`, with the same name as the last component of the path.

Comment: so need to update the spec file? %{_sourcedir} in place of Source:/root/test.sh??

Comment: No, you must put test.sh in that directory. `rpm -E "%{sourcedir}"`

Comment: but test.sh already in /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES as you said -:(

Comment: I copy /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES/test.sh to /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/test.sh